# Conversion of Video background to colored background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a video as background after the completion of video I would like to change the video background to colour background like red green or some any colour. I am trying in HTML5 but got stuck. Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: There is a high chance that we can help you, but we need the code you have got stuck with. You can also share the screenshots of your issue. The more information you provide about your issue - the higher are the chances that SO users will be able to help you.

Comment: can u update some example code to fiddle?

Comment: Have You Tried Anything Yet? Than Paste Code!

Comment: try my code, may be this will help you

Answer (score 0):

try this code, as per my understanding may be this is what you are searching for, here after completion of video in the background, i have changed body background color to red.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('video').on('ended',function(){
    $("video").first().attr('src','')
         $('html, body').css('background','red');
    });
  });
```

```css
#header {
  border-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.featured-area {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#recent-posts {
  margin-top: 27px;
}
#blurb {
  margin-bottom: 27px;
  width: 75%;
}
.recent-post-box {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding-top: 4px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
#logo {
  display: none;
}
#hero {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
#hero #bg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: url("http://www.makemeapro.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/hero-cover-modified.jpg");
  opacity: .4;
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background-size:cover;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#outerDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hero video {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    object-fit:cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<div id="hero">
<div id="bg">
     <video autoplay>
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
      </video>
    
</div>
<table id="outerDiv" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" id="innerDiv">
<div class="post-header"><h1 style="color: #383838;">Helping young professionals navigate the world of work.</h1></div>
<div align="center"><button class="btn">JOIN THE REVOLUTION</button></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

</body> 
</html>
```